# GROUPING() in hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, aggregate-functions, teradata

I have given query , compatible to teradata. It have imported table in dimension_tab using Sqoop. Tried to execute on HIVE , but unfortunately compatible to hive.

```
SELECT fact_1_id,
       fact_2_id,
       SUM(sales_value) AS sales_value,
       GROUPING(fact_1_id) AS f1g, 
       GROUPING(fact_2_id) AS f2g
FROM   dimension_tab
GROUP BY CUBE (fact_1_id, fact_2_id)
ORDER BY fact_1_id, fact_2_id;
```

Then I tried to make it HIVE compatible. Refer : WIKI

Fortunately,CUBE is available in HIVE , but with different syntax

i.e. **fact_1_id, fact_2_id WITH CUBE** . but form documentation, GROUPING() is not available in HIVE.

Please help me if GROUPING() function is available in HIVE. 
or 
How can I make query running on HIVE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have `NULL` values for the `id`, just use simple logic:

```
SELECT fact_1_id,
       fact_2_id,
       SUM(sales_value) AS sales_value,
       (case when fact_1_id is null then 1 else 0 end) as f1g,
       (case when fact_2_id is null then 1 else 0 end) as f2
FROM   dimension_tab
GROUP BY fact_1_id, fact_2_id WITH CUBE
ORDER BY fact_1_id, fact_2_id;
```

This logic (not the `WITH CUBE`, of course) will work in both Teradata and Hive.

Otherwise, if you do have NULL values, you can use `GROUPING__ID`:

```
SELECT fact_1_id,
       fact_2_id,
       SUM(sales_value) AS sales_value,
       (case when (CAST (GROUPING__ID AS INT) & 1) = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as f1g,
       (case when (CAST (GROUPING__ID AS INT) & 2) = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as f2g
FROM   dimension_tab
GROUP BY fact_1_id, fact_2_id WITH CUBE
ORDER BY fact_1_id, fact_2_id;
```

NOTE:  `GROUPING__ID` depends on the order of the expressions in the `group by`, so rearranging the `group by` can change the meanings of the flag.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon .... for detailed answer.  just to confirm if i got correctly ..even if order changes ....we need to change  '& N' accordingly and will perfectly in all cases.

Comment: @Sanjiv . . . The "N" value after the `&` is 2^ position of the expression in the `group by`.  Why Hive didn't just do the right thing and creating a `grouping()` function, I don't know.  The SQL compiler should know the ordering of the `group by` expressions.

Comment: Yeah, Raised HIVE JIRA for the same . https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10310